1 year old citrus plant leaves browning
I'm very new to growing any citrus plants. Last year I decided to plant some lemon seeds that I got from lemons from the store, just as a sort of "will this even grow"
This plant is now about a year old, it'd been fairly healthy till recently where I've noticed more and more of the leaves have started going brown and crispy. it's mostly the older leaves but I'm not sure what's happening.
I'm in the UK, so it's been pretty chilly, as spring rolled around about ~2 months ago, it started growing a lot again after being dormant during winter. but then about 2/3 weeks ago completely stopped. but it has been quite chilly in the UK still for some context, dropping below 10 degrees. my plants stayed indoors pretty much it's whole life.
I water the plant about every 1-2 weeks depending on how dry the surface looks. Once a month, id been using the baby bio citrus food fertiliser, as per instructions on the packaging, but I've stopped fertlising for the last month. the plant also sits next to a South facing window, with the window open occasionally. The temperature recently has stayed between 15-18 degrees near the plant.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I love this little plant, don't want it to die :(





I had a similar experience with a lemon tree I planted from seeds a few years ago. Whenever I noticed the leaves turning brown or becoming crispy, it was almost always related to watering. Citrus roots are quite shallow, so they don’t handle being too dry or too waterlogged very well.
For me, using a light potting mix with good drainage made a big difference. I also started watering more frequently but with smaller amounts each time, and I saw a noticeable improvement.
I’ve also found that sudden temperature changes can stress citrus plants. When temperatures drop quickly or fluctuate, my lemon tree shows signs of stress. This spring, I moved it outside too early, and the trunk actually cracked from the shock. Thankfully, it's recovering well—they’re surprisingly resilient plants.
For what it’s worth, I’ve never used a stake to support mine, and it seems to be doing fine without one.
I hope my experience helps you a bit!

Your soil looks a tad dry. Add Distilled water (Only use distilled or collected rainwater for plants), Common sign of lack of humidity. Citrus grows in humid climates so it needs warm moisture. Put a clear plastic bag over it and add a bit of water as it sits in the sun. 
Second citrus plants have differing fertilizer needs. Citrus fertilizer or any with a NPK rating 2-1-1
